# Different ordering for KroneckerDelta?

Tags: replacement

I have an expression like this:

[image]

```
Assuming[m [\Element] Integers && n [\Element] Integers, 1/2 I J n (4-m n+n^2) KroneckerDelta[m,-n]]//FullSimplify
```

Now, since `KroneckerDelta` has attribute `Orderless`, that means it will sort things into canonical order, and since my expression has $n^2$ in it, I assume that's why it's evaluating the Kronecker for m->-n (I tried putting KroneckerDelta[n,-m] but got the same result). Now, technically this is correct. But I'd like that my expression was given in terms of `m`, not `n`. If I manually replace `n` by `-m` I get the desired output

$$-iJm(2+m^2)$$

but I'd like to get that automatically within Mathematica. Is that possible without explicitly doing the replacement `/.n->-m`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order depends of alphabetical ordering of `n` and `m`. Therefore exist simple solution with renaming `n` and `m`

```
FullSimplify[1/2 I J m (4 - n m + m^2) KroneckerDelta[n, -m]] /. {n -> m, m -> n}
```

[image]

Comment: I guess that will do :) Thanks

Comment: @dingo_d Since you've got more than 15 rep. you can upvote answers too. I'm just reminding because I see you've accepted  answer with no upvote what is strange.

Comment: Oh, sometimes I totally forget to do that :S Sorry, upvoated it now ^^